# ESXi 5.5 -> 7.03 direct upgrade?

Tags: vmware-esxi

I'm looking into a long-overdue upgrade from ESXi 5.5

The server is a standalone, bare metal server at OVH

I intend to mount the iso over the virtual java kvm

Can I upgrade to 7.03 directly, or do I have to take intermediate steps over 6.x?

The cpu is compatible with 7.03
the vmfs is 5.60, also compatible with ESXi 7.03, at least the spec say that vmfs5 is compatible both <=6 and >=6.5

Are any problems to be anticipated, or should it just work after 7.03 is installed?

Answer (score 2):

> Can I upgrade to 7.03 directly, or do I have to take intermediate
> steps over 6.x?

No, you can't, you can upgrade to v7 from v6.7 and v6.5 only - it's literally written in the documentation.

> Are any problems to be anticipated, or should it just work after 7.03
> is installed?

It just won't work, at all.

Also, have you checked ALL of your host HW in the 7.0u3 HCL? Just because the CPU might be in it doesn't mean the rest of it will be - there were major changes in what hardware was supported on both 6.7 and 7.

Comment: Would the installer-iso try to install, ruin the setup, or just do "I'm sorry Dave, I cannot do that" if incompatible hardware?

Comment: The latter, it just won't let you.